# What would it take to spark through electrical tape?

Tags: spark

Forgetting for a moment that wires can get hot, and that electrical tape can melt because of it: I've been wondering how much voltage/amperage it would take to spark through your standard house hold electrical tape. While the electrical tape is an insulator, nothing is a perfect insulator, right? It's just a matter of resistance, isn't it?

Comment: When in school, I heard 3M electrical tape insulates to 1,000v per mil. That's much better than air.

Comment: As a general rule, electrical wiring materials intended for household use are good to at least 600V.  (Some industrial stuff, of course, is rated much higher.)

Comment: And it's not a matter of resistance, usually, but rather (as mentioned below) "breakdown voltage" -- the voltage at which the electric field is strong enough to essentially disassemble the material.

Comment: (Some high-voltage insulators are actually built using materials that intentionally have a lower than possible resistance, so that the electric field will be uniformly distributed along the insulator rather than possibly building up in one place.)

Comment: It's quite high, as some have noted, however it's not something you should trust your life to. Insulators can have pinholes. There's usually a healthy derating between the typical breakdown voltage and where a sensible engineer would actually use it (as well as multiple layers etc.).

Comment: In any case think about that the electrical tape it is not like the original cable insulator. See carefully if the temperatur rating characteristics of tape is for the material (PVC e.t.c) or to the glue. Many times glue melting in lower temperatures than the manufacturer states.

Comment: Can you call it "electrical tape" if it doesn't even print this breakdown voltage figure on the package?　In Japan, this household stuff is just called vinyl tape (bini-ru te-pu): [ビニールテープ](https://www.google.com/search?q=ビニールテープ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [dielectric breakdown voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_strength) of electrical tape. For [this 3M brand](http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/223990O/scotch-super-88-vinyl-electrical-tape.pdf?fn=Scotch%20Super%2088%20Tape%20DS.pdf) it's 10kV.

So, if you get to about 10,000 volts, it'll spark through. For the equivalent thickness of air (0.216mm) it would only take 648 volts to spark.

Once it's been sparked through once, the insulating properties for that spot are probably greatly reduced. It'd require much less to spark through the same spot again.

The resistance is another matter. It's rated at 1e6 megohms, so some very very small current will flow at any voltage.